# Send data posted on server to contact on Whatsapp and phone

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a form that needs to be filled by the user including phone number.
After the data is entered, it will be stored on server side.
Now what I want is to send each of the contact stored on server, some of the details filled by him like some text or image. And this things would be sent automatically on his phone as SMS and also on Whatsapp if he has installed in his mobile.
      Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to send some detail from server to user's device via SMS and whatsapp??

Comment: Yes Mrugesh. So is this the ios coding part or the server side coding or process?

Comment: It's a server side process. you can not do that via iOS coding

Comment: I think for SMS sending you need to buy SMS server...